# Handling Response Text in React Admin

Tags: react-admin

I am using React-Admin and Postgresql.

I'm looking to capture the response data that I am sending in a failed post response and display that in the UI, but I have no idea if this is possible or not. I see some of the react-admin api for onFailure and onSuccess but I can't make it do what I want.

My response is

`{'data': failure_reasons}, HTTPStatus.HTTP_I_AM_A_TEAPOT`

Failure_reasons can be whatever you want...a dict or a list.

I'm super new to react-admin and javascript so keep that in mind. Thanks.

Comment: Could you past the related part of your dataProvider?

Comment: Hey, sorry I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Which dataProvider are you using? If it's a custom one, can you paste the code?

Answer (score 0):

Actually `onSuccess` and `onError` seems to be the good way to achieve this:

```
  const handleFailure = (error) => {
    // handle you error and parse it here
    notify(`Something bad happened: ${error}`), 'error');
  };

  const handleSuccess = (data) => {
    notify('Success!');
    redirect('show', props.basePath, data.id);
    refresh();
  };

  return (
    <Edit
      {...props}
      onFailure={handleFailure}
      onSuccess={handleSuccess}
    >
      ...
    </Edit>
  );
```